# How do I mount a file on top of a broken symbolic link?

Tags: chroot, resolv.conf, bind-mount, resolvconf

In preparation of a chroot I'm doing an `mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf ${MOUNTPOINT}/etc/resolv.conf`. I need this because the `${MOUNTPOINT}` contains a broken `etc/resolv.conf`.

However, `mount` is missing the point of the operation. It complains that `${MOUNTPOINT}/etc/resolv.conf` "is a symbolic link to nowhere". Yes, I know. That's why I'm doing the rebind in the first place.

[edit] By request, `/etc/resolv.conf` is a normal file:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42 Feb  6 12:52 /etc/resolv.conf

with normal content

> nameserver 192.168.4.1

This should also be used *after* the chroot, but not by changing the actual `${MOUNTPOINT}/etc/resolv.conf`. That should remain as-is:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 14  2017 ${MOUNTPOINT}/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

(Background: I know about rebinding `/run/` in the context of `resolv.conf`. Doesn't work for me, `/etc/resolv.conf` is a real file and not a symbolic link. It's only `${MOUNTPOINT}/etc/resolv.conf` that's broken, and it's only broken during the `chroot` so I can't just overwrite it).

Comment: I honestly got lot. Would you add `la -la /etc/resolv.conf` output to the question?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Are you aware of bind mounts, especially for files? They are a tad obscure, I know.

Comment: I only have used it to  mount directories. resolvconf/dnsmask might be getting in your way, and I would not use any of them in a server setting.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: resolvconf is indeed getting in my way during the `chroot`. That's what I'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: I do not use resolvconf in any of my Debian servers.

Comment: why not replacing the link with an actual empty file ?

Comment: @Kiwy: Because the challenge is not to touch the link. After I'm done with the `chroot` and have umounted everything, the link should be untouched.

Comment: [...good luck !](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395458/22142)

Comment: @don_crissti: That's the _source_. In my case, the symlink merely happens to be in the place where the bind hides it. But as we know from regular directories used as mount points, Unix & Linux have no problem hiding stuff underneath a mount.

Comment: The point was that when using `mount` the paths are resolved first (source _and_ destination)... and in your case the destination can't be resolved.

Comment: Simply copy the `/etc/resolv.conf` to your chroot.

Comment: @GAD3R: See question and previous comments. The challenge is NOT to alter the actual file system.

Comment: IMO making r/w mounts weakens a chroot environment.